# Vector points from CSV file wrong location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am using QGIS 1.8 (I know old version), and uploaded a CSV file with coordinates. The underlying base map is from Google, using the OpenLayers plugin. This base map uses WGS84-EPSG:3857, and my vector points from the CSV are using WGS84-EPSG:4326. This difference shouldn't be a problem I thought to have read in here:

[EPSG 3857 or 4326 for GoogleMaps, OpenStreetMap and Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet)

The strange thing is that, my points appear on the map just about 30 kilometres next to the actual location. If I used the wrong projection or coordinate system then the point would have been on the other side of the world. A colleague of me uses the exact same file and we think he enters the same settings, at least the same CRS, and his points are in the right spot. Does anyone knows what the problem might be?

Comment: I believe that for some GDAL versions EPSG:3857 and EPSG:900913 did not mean the same http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83975/why-is-tiff-different-in-epsg-3857-and-epsg-900913-in-gdal. I recommend to update and if not possible, test with 3857 vs. 900913.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and also am installing the newest version of QGIS. Hopefully that does the trick! :)